# Book about water world with islands that moved with the waves and tides

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for some help on a book I read 30 years or so ago. I remember it was a world that was all water or oceans; there were islands that moved with the waves and tides. I think some of the characters were giants, long legged and mobile. Unfortunately, I can not remember much more detail at this moment so this may be impossible to rediscover. The writing style seemed to be quite descriptive about the moving islands and the ocean that has creatures also living there.

Thank you for any help and I appreciate any assistance; by the way I am a newbie here and am extremely grateful;This was a paperback and was an older book

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might be C. S. Lewis' ["Perelandra"](http://books.google.com/books/about/Perelandra.html?id=CuB-_oPH1GIC). It has a water planet (Venus) with floating islands. I don't recall giants, but that could be a memory from "Out of the Silent Plant" creeping in.

[image]

Comment: I quickly read over some of the pages on google, and it does seem to be the right one. I am going to pick the book up and read through. thank you for your amazing and extremely fast help Joe L and System Down for editing my question to make it an excellent one. :)

Comment: @user29001 Thank you! Perelandra was my favorite of Lewis' "Space Trilogy". The description of Venus-as-Eden was so hauntingly beautiful it's always stayed close to my heart (a little maudlin, but a bit of schmaltz is good for you sometimes).

Comment: Once I started reading Perelandra, all the memories of the series came charging back. Thank you again, I just wish I found SF&F sooner....lol