# 1960-70 sci-fi book about a man who lands on a planet of water with islands

Tags: story-identification

The story starts with a man getting into a coffin size rocket and launching into outer space with no provisions. He lands on a planet of water with floating islands. The islands all have different forms of vegetation and animals on each one. There is one stationary island with transdimensional Adam and Eve type deities.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60633/book-about-water-world-with-islands-that-moved-with-the-waves-and-tides/60634#60634

Answer (score 9):

This is *Perelandra*, the second of *Space Trilogy* by C.S. Lewis.

[Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perelandra)

> (also titled Voyage to Venus in a later edition published by Pan
>   Books) is the second book in the Space Trilogy of C. S. Lewis, set in
>   the Field of Arbol. It was first published in 1943.